# Measuring the performance of a clustering algorithm with "true" clusters available

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, model-evaluation

Suppose I have observational units $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Each of these units is in a known cluster $C_1, \dots, C_m$, $m < n$. A ML algorithm generates based on a metric new clusters $C^{*}_1, \dots, C^{*}_p$, $p$ not necessarily equal to $m$.

Is there a standard way to measure the performance of the ML algorithm?

Best-case scenario is the following: $m = p$ and for each $C^{*}_i$, there exists some $C_j$ such that $C^{*}_i = C_j$, where equality is defined by having the same observational units.

**Edit as clarification**: The reason I'm doing this in the first place is because I have $N > n$ units available, with the remaining $N - n$ units not having known clusters. I'd like to see how well the algorithm performs with the $n$ units before I scale it up to the remaining $N-n$ units.

Comment: If you know the “clusters” how this is not a classification?

Comment: @Tim Forgive me if I'm misinterpreting you, but the reason I'm doing this in the first place is because I have $N > n$ units available, with the remaining $N - n$ units not having known clusters. I'd like to see how well the algorithm performs with the $n$ units before I scale it up to the remaining $N-n$ units.

Comment: If n is large enough, a classifier might help to increase training set size or do some sort of semi-supervised learning.  Might be relevant https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116906/semi-supervised-clustering-high-dimensional-data?rq=1

Comment: Have you heard of the external clustering criteria aka external cluster validity indices? These are measures to compare cluster solutions or a cluster solution with a "true" partition.

Comment: @ttnphns No, I've not. I would appreciate a detailed answer if you have time to write one up, but I'll get searching on this myself soon.

Comment: Please visit my web page and pick "Compare partitions" collection. There you find most important criteria with the formulas, described in KO_cluagree macro.

Answer (score 1):

A great discussion of clustering in a Bayesian framework appears in:
Hanson, Robin, John Stutz, and Peter Cheeseman. "Bayesian Classification Theory." http://robinhanson.com/ijcai91.pdf

> ... the AutoClass system searches for the most probable classifications, automatically choosing the number of classes and complexity of class descriptions ...

> ... evaluation function optimally trades off the complexity of the model with its fit to the data, and is used
> to guide an open-ended search for the best classification ...

Note AutoClass does not use "true" clusters, and has a history of illuminating new meaningful classes to subject matter experts. https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/rse/synthesis-projects-applications/autoclass/